# York linear regression with fixed origin

Tags: regression, measurement-error

I am trying to perform a linear regression toa data with known x and y errors. The method I am using is called [York linear regression](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.1632486).

How do I fix the origin for this method, so it only fits the slope?